# Loading web app jars in order using maven - same as websphereclassloaderMode="PARENT_LAST" in websphere

Tags: maven, websphere, ear, maven-ear-plugin

I'm deploying to websphere using the maven plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/usage.html. I need to set the ordering of when the project jars are loaded, so that the project jars are loaded for a given application prior to websphere common jars. For websphere the config used is `websphereclassloaderMode="PARENT_LAST"` within "deployment.xml". Can I configure this property using maven ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no existing plugin that automatically configures this particular WAS property or file, but you can simply create the `deployment.xml` file containing this property within the [EAR source directory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#earSourceDirectory) (by default, `src/main/application`). For example: `src/main/application/META-INF/ibmconfig/cells/defaultCell/applications/defaultApp/deployments/defaultApp/deployment.xml`.